# Change ActionBar Background Color Dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to know is it possible to change [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) (in [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)) Background Color dynamically according to selected page in viewpager or selected actionbar tabs. I have tried with the following code. But, it doesn't work. Please help.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);    

        if(position == 0){
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
        }else if(position == 1){
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
        }else{
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Firstly make in onPageSelected a Toast which one will shown which position did you click propably it can shows wrong position

Comment: I had tested with Toast. The position is corrected. I have only three pages in ViewPager.

Answer (score 6):

Please try like this

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffFEBB31"));
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Comment: Normally, this code is working. But, when put it in onPageSelected(int  position) funtion of mViewPager, it doesn't work. On page in viewpager changed, the background color of actionbar changes to white.

Comment: This did work, but what about changing the statusBar color dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

Make something like this:

```
         actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(Color.BLACK);
```

It is the easiest way

Comment: This will not work - setBackgroundDrawable() needs a Drawable reference not an *int*.